# Help with contour lines in circuitikz - unwanted circles appeared

Tags: circuitikz

I am doing this scheme in LaTeX.

and I wrote this code. I think everything is good but these lines contours inside this scheme. This red and blue dashed lines. I get these circles with arrows or something like that, and I don't know why. Beside that, I want to ask you how to get these corners rounded, because adding did not help at all. Thanks.

Comment: Why have you removed the code from your questions? It's pointless, as it's still there in the [revision history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/370776/revisions) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, why there are these symbols, but  if you exchange the `to` with `--` everything is ok:

```
\draw[>=latex',red,dashed,rounded corners=10pt,->](0.5,1.5) -- (0.5,2.5) -- (4.5,2.5) -- (4.5,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5);
\draw[>=latex',blue,dashed,rounded corners=10pt,->](9.5, 1.5) -- (9.5,2.5) -- (14.5, 2.5) -- (14.5, 0.5) -- (9.5, 0.5);
```

EDIT: There was a bug in circuitikz, therefore, the surgearrester appears at to-paths without []-option. This is fixed at the current git-version.